# Is there a way to group_by values in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks something like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Accepted | Did not accept |
| Did not accept | Did not accept |

and so on..

Just wanted to know if there is a way to manipulate the data into a table visualisation which looks something like this?: To count the number of Accepted and Did not accept for each column.

| Accepted or not? | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Accepted | 10 | 2 |
| Did not accept | 5 | 5 |

Comment: have you read this article https://towardsdatascience.com/grouping-data-with-r-ef95cee48dc6?gi=ebae8a9180bf

Answer (score 1):

In base R, use `sapply` with `table` -

```
sapply(df,function(x) table(factor(x, levels = c('Accepted', 'Did not accept'))))

#               Column.A Column.B
#Accepted              1        0
#Did not accept        1        2
```

In `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = name, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

#  value          Column.A Column.B
#  <chr>             <int>    <int>
#1 Accepted              1        0
#2 Did not accept        1        2
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Column.A = c("Accepted", "Did not accept"), Column.B = c("Did not accept", 
"Did not accept")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What happens if I have more than 2 columns, but only want to show Column.A and Column.B only?

Comment: If you have `cols <- c('Column.A', 'Column.B')` for base R option you can do `sapply(df[cols],function(x) ..)` whereas for `tidyverse` include `select` first `df %>% select(all_of(cols)) %>% pivot_longer(...) %>% pivot_wider(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert wide-to-long, then tabulate:

```
table(stack(df))
#                 ind
# values           Column.A Column.B
#   Accepted              1        0
#   Did not accept        1        2
```